# Correctly Setting Up Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup a new iphone app to play around with Firebase.  I'm trying to use Cocoapods to import it, but I keep getting a

```
'No such module' error
```

The Firebase files are in the pods directory, but Xcode can't find them.

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProj' do
  pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.3'
  pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
end

target 'MyProjTests' do
end

target 'MyProjUITests' do
end
```

This is a basic hello world app, and the only code I have added is:

```
'import Firebase'
'import Alamofire'
```

I run 'pod install' with xcode closed. 
I launch the app with .xcworkspace

There is no Pods.xcconfig file.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a "full Monte" Podfile? Verbatim cut & paste

Comment: Skip down to the first section called "Install Your First Dependency" and give this a whirl. http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: This is Podfile, cut and paste:  platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.3'  The same as above

Comment: I haven't messed w/ Firebase, but there are 2 things to check. 1) Make sure you've got the project closed when you're doing `pod install` and 2) Make sure you open the WORKSPACE, not the project after you install the pod.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I checked out the link and set up a new project exactly the way specified, and still get the same error

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately, that's how I'm doing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97025/discussion-between-adrian-b-and-scott).

Comment: If you're installing just Firebase, do you need 'pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
` in the RW tutorial?

Comment: Might want to take a peek at this post, too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30248883/4475605

Comment: Thank you Adrian for your thoughtful comments.  For the life of me, I have no idea why it wasn't working.  After deleting the project and reinstalling the cocoapods gem and rebuilding everything multiple times, it is now working.  I don't know why it is working or wasn't before, but, frankly, I'm just glad to move on.  The link you posted was helpful in revealing how projects are configured.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That podfile looks wonky for a brand new one. Are you using Swift?

Also, for a *brand new* project, you would not have 'AlamoFire' in the pod file.

I have had a couple of issues with Cocoapods so my first suggestion is to re-install it

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then, walk through the Firebase Guide to set up a new App. I just did the steps and it works correctly and sets up a pod file thats slightly different than yours.

[iOS Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html)

I modified my pod file as such:

```
target 'Swift Firebase Test' do

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'FirebaseOSX', '>= 2.4.2'

end
```

Be sure to change to your project directory before initializing Cocoapods in your project.

Once you've done that, compile the app and see if there are any errors.

oh - and ensure the AppDelegate.swift is correct.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation
import Firebase

@NSApplicationMain
```

Comment: Thank you Jay for your help.  After deleting the project and reinstalling the cocoapods gem and rebuilding everything multiple times, it is now working.  I don't know why it is working or wasn't before, but, frankly, I'm just glad to move on.  I've tested a number of different setups for the Podfile has all of the podfiles outside of the target blocks.  This is a normal Gemfile setup.  Ruby executes all gems outside of blocks and selectively executes the one inside them.  Still I appreciate your help; thanks again.