# Can't import AFNetworking from CocoaPods in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods

In Podfile  I

```
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'
```

pod update and I open project using xcworkspace.

And everything  gone my way,but:

when i import AFNetworking ,Xcode prompt `'No such module AFNetworking'`

I searched the solution for this question, and did like this:    in  'Built setting ->User Header Search Paths ' add `${SRCROOT}` and choose recursive.

But it didn't  work . Xcode throw the same mesage :`'No such module AFNetworking'`

Comment: If you are in swift, did you written `use_frameworks!` below the `platform :ios, '8.0'` ?

Comment: did you run pod install after adding AFNetworking in PodFile?

Comment: I wrritten this  # use_frameworks! below the platform : ios, '8.0'

Comment: @Ivan Yuriev I  had run pod install and even run pod update.

Comment: did you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994331/no-such-module-restkit-with-cocoapods-and-swift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay,I just did a mistake  operation .

```
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 use_frameworks!
```

Two line above is necessary ! After I added them and run `pod update`, my project's `Link Binary With Libraries` add a row contain Pods_.framework .Then I import AFNetworking  is OK.

check out there :[No such module 'RestKit' with cocoapods and swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994331/no-such-module-restkit-with-cocoapods-and-swift)

Answer (score 2):

Go to

**Project** > **General** > **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

When press "**Plus**" and add your framework from list.