# Cocoapods: no such module 'CorePlot'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have an Objective-C project.

- Most of files are written in Objc
- Several custom `UIView` classes are written in Swift.
- Specially one of `UIViewController` subclass using Core-Plot is written in Objc.

It has no problem, until...
Now, I am trying to create a new `UIViewController` using Core-Plot written in Swift.

Trying to use `import CorePlot` to import external framework Core-Plot as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). But the compiler shows the error "No such module 'CorePlot'"

Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'Meters' do
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Meters
  pod 'PQFCustomLoaders', '~> 1.1.0'
  pod 'CorePlot'
end
```

- I have used `pod install` and 'pod update'
- I tried "Clean and rebuild"

Neither works for me. Please let me know if any other information needed.

Comment: Does it mean I can't use the same external framework for two files, one written in Objc, the other written in Swift?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994331/no-such-module-restkit-with-cocoapods-and-swift ? Did you open .xcodeworkspace and no xcodeproj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build pods as frameworks (uncomment `use_frameworks!` in the pod file) to create modules. Core Plot will work fine that way but I don't know about the other pod you're using.