# What is `Pods/Local Podspecs` folder for?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I have one curious beginner question. I have an react native project for ios and getting through the folders, but I don't understand what is folder `Pods/Local Podspecs` for?

- What is it purpose?
- how it is created (is it generated or I have to do it)

Comment: Read pod documentation[https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html ].

Comment: good resource to study Specs, but there is noting about folder "Local Podspec" ... what is this exact folder for? ... how and when it is used, for which purpose? from where it come from? ... to understand me, I didn't write the project from scratch, I just came to already done so I have to reverse engineer it, and I didn't find answer in documentation ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a development pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199431/what-is-a-development-pod)

Comment: Local podsec and development Pods are different things. A Podspec describes a version of a Pod library. A pod can have different podspec over a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

A Podspec, or Spec, describes a version of a Pod library.

We can use a local path to a directory on your computer and write a Podspec in that directory and use CocoaPods. This is called local podsec.